# textbox stops working after recreation

Tags: java, android

When my app starts I do this in **onStart** method:

```
if (MainActivity.s_polarDeviceService == null) {
    MainActivity.s_polarDeviceService = new PolarDeviceService(this, mHandler);
    PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
    wl.acquire();
}
```

*PolarDeviceService* class is regular class which spawns a thread which connects/reconnects to polar bluetooth device and reads data from it.

When I hit **'back'** button on my phone my activity gets destroyed, and when I spawn it again it gets recreated normally, but all controls on view are not reacting. For example, this code, which is executed from activity handler, has no effect:

```
SensorData sensorData =(SensorData) msg.obj;
TextView txtBpm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_output);
TextView txtMinBpm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_min);
TextView txtMaxBpm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_max);
TextView txtAvgBpm = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_avg);
TextView txtSensorStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtSensorStatus);
txtBpm.setText("BPM: " + sensorData.getBpm());
txtMaxBpm.setText("max: " + sensorData.getMaxBpm());
txtMinBpm.setText("min: " + sensorData.getMinBpm());
txtAvgBpm.setText("avg: " + sensorData.getAvgBpm());
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was that after recreation of Activity, my service still had old Handler reference which wasn't executing on new UI thread.